How to make a table fill all tcolorbox, without inner margins?
I use tcolorbox to make a box on a page. I want to reproduce a table like this inside the box, where the left and right borders of the table are the tcolorbox:

However, with this MWE there are inner margins in the tcolorbox and the table does not stretches to fill in all the width and height:
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tcolorbox}[%
        breakable,
        notitle,
        toptitle=1mm,
        bottomtitle=2mm,
        width=\textwidth,
        center,
        parbox=false,
        sharp corners=all,
        colback=white,
        colframe=black,
        boxrule=0.3mm,
        subtitle style={colback=white, coltext=black, bottomrule=0pt},
        colbacktitle=lightgray,
        coltitle=black]
        
        \tcbsubtitle{}
        \begin{center}
            \begin{tblr}{%
                    width = \textwidth,
                    colspec = {X|X|X|X}}
                \hline
                one & two & three & four \\
                \hline
            \end{tblr}
        \end{center}
        
        \tcbsubtitle{}
        \begin{center}
            \begin{tblr}{%
                    width = \textwidth,
                    colspec = {X|X|X|X}}
                \hline
                one & two & three & four \\
                \hline
            \end{tblr}
        \end{center}
    \end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}

How can I make the table to fill full width and height?

See the examples on pp. 76 of the manual

Are you looking for size=minimal?

With left*=0mm,right*=0mm,bottom=0mm,boxsep=0mm and \noindent
\documentclass[]{article}
% \usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[%
    breakable,
    notitle,
    toptitle=1mm,
    bottomtitle=2mm,
    width=\textwidth,
    center,
    parbox=false,
    sharp corners=all,
    colback=white,
    colframe=black,
    boxrule=0.3mm,
    subtitle style={colback=white, coltext=black, bottomrule=0pt},
    colbacktitle=lightgray,
    coltitle=black,
    left*=0mm,right*=0mm,bottom=0mm,boxsep=0mm%<--- added
    ]
    
    \tcbsubtitle{}
    % \begin{center}
    \noindent\begin{tblr}{%
            width = \textwidth,
            colspec = {X|X|X|X}}
        \hline
        one & two & three & four \\
        \hline
    \end{tblr}
    % \end{center}
    \tcbsubtitle{}
    %\begin{center}
        \noindent\begin{tblr}{%
                width = \textwidth,
                colspec = {X|X|X|X}}
            \hline
            one & two & three & four \\
            \hline
        \end{tblr}
    %\end{center}    
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}


